# Limited checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to select all checked checkboxes, **except** checkboxes having a class `.checkall`.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1961" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkall" class="checkbox checkall">
```

Script:

```
$("input.checkbox:checkbox:checked:not(.checkall)").each(function () {
    var checkbox = $(this), machineId = checkbox.val()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just posted on your other post about this, use:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked:not(.checkall)")
```

This is the 'regular' way to check for input tags of a particular type, it's much clearer than your way. I'm not sure what the significance of the `.checkbox` class is but it seems like it's not necessary to my.

I also recommend you cache your check boxes in a variable and search that multiple times. That way you're only searching the check boxes each time instead of the whole DOM.

```
// in document ready
var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

// When you need to find the checked check boxes
var checked = checkboxes.find(':checked:not(.checkall)');
```

Answer (score 3):

Addionally to @Tyriar's answer:

You possibly could optimize the selection even more depending on where the checkboxes are in the HTML by making the selector more specific and possibly modifying the HTML to help with that.

For example, if all checkboxes are the same element, add it's ID (or class) as a parent in the selector:

```
$("#mytable input[type=checkbox]:checked:not(.checkall)")
```

Also `:not` isn't very efficient. If the "check all" checkboxes were, for example, in the `thead` of a table while the checkboxes you need are in the `tbody` then use:

```
$("#mytable tbody input[type=checkbox]:checked")
```